# Changes to local hosts file lost

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

When staging websites locally, I edit my hosts file to point a given URL to localhost, so I can preview sites with the correct URL for link testing, etc.

To do so, I run

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

then edit my file and save with `:wq`.

This works fine until I reboot. As soon as I restart, my changes are lost.

However, only changes I've made that reference localhost (like `127.0.0.1 www.somesite.com`) are wiped out. Changes I've made to point to staging servers (like `555.555.55.5 www.anothersite.com`) remain.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please consider posting this to [Super User](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: I wondered about that - how can I move it over?

Comment: Or request for it to be moved over, rather.

Comment: Not sure. You could just open another question there, put a comment with the link to the new question here and close this question.

Comment: Adding a 127.0.0.1 entry to my localhost via vi works fine after reboot.

What OS are you using ?

Comment: OSX. Thanks, Kassym. Not sure why it's not working for me.

Comment: What version of OSX ? I"m Using 10.7.2

Comment: I'm running a VPN client that I believe writes to the hosts file. Maybe that is causing the issue.

Comment: I think this is related to the VPN client writing to the host file, as another colleague with the client installed is having the same issue.